# Facebook login and user_likes stopped working without any code change

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-php-sdk

I have a facebook login implementation which takes user permission for user_likes and we check if the user has liked a certain page or not. The code has been working without any problem for last 6 months or so.

Suddenly about 2 weeks back it stooped working and was not giving any values for the user_likes. The facebook app was created before April 2014 so API V2.0 constrains does not apply.

My base code for facebook access is this

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'         => $app_id,
    'secret'        => $app_secret,
    ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){

   try{
            // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            $user = NULL;
    }
}

if($user){
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}else{
    // Get login URL
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope'                 => 'user_likes, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos,email',
            'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
            ));
}

if($user){

    // Save your method calls into an array
    $fields='id,name,first_name,last_name,email,username,gender,location,birthday,link,locale';
    $queries = array(
            array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/me?fields='.$fields),
            array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/friends'),
            array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/likes'),
            array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => '/'.$user.'/interests'),
            );

    // POST your queries to the batch endpoint on the graph.
    try{
            $batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.json_encode($queries), 'POST');
    }catch(Exception $o){
            error_log($o);
    }
```

It was showing "csrf state token does not match one provided" error in the logs so I updated the PHP-SDK hoping it will fix things for me, and it did. Everything started working fine, however after 3-4 days it stopped working again, now I cant even get users to login with facebook.

Does anyone has any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: I think the new PHP SDK uses v2.0 by default. try prepending the calls with `/v1.0`...

Comment: Yes I tried that but still users cant seem to login with facebook.